# addEvenetListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why do I get the error `addEventListener` is not a function?

```
var name = $(".name").val();

name.addEventListener('keyup', function() {

alert("good");

});
```

Comment: You needn't use addEventListener if you're using jQuery, it comes with a plethora of event handlers... https://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: Because it cannot be applied directly to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `name` is a text value, as you've set it to `$(".name").val()`. Just use `$(".name")`:

```
var name = $(".name");
```

Also note that `name` is a jQuery object, so it's better practice to do something a little like this:

```
$(".name").on("keyup", function() {
  alert("Good");
});
```

Because you don't actually need the intermediary variable `name`.